Does Windows support static and pretty hostnames?
Question

Does Windows 11 support the concept of a --static and --pretty hostname, like SystemD's hostnamectl command does (and more broadly, almost all Linux-based OSes do)?
Rationale

I ask because on Fedora and OSTW, I can set a static hostname to something actually static (like a base 36-encoded timestamp [1] and the --pretty hostname to something that usefully describes the machine. However, on Windows, I am forced to register each machine like I'm naming a variable: machine_ID_for_PURPOSE, which means that their names aren't particularly descriptive nor constant.
This isn't a matter of debate, like using PowerShell's ${I can name this variable anything that UTF-8 permits} - being able to have a consistent identifier irrespective of how I decide to fill the --pretty field should be fairly objectively an improvement (we have IDs on social media profiles despite having usernames).

Yes; On Windows the name of the machine, based on the documentation for hostnamectl, close to a static hostname while a pretty hostname is supported by editing hosts. The length of the name, of a machine name for Windows is limited, so you would have to utilize the hosts file to generate a hostname with a timestamp.

@Ramhound, I don't see anything evidently relevant in %SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts. Do you have the time to elaborate?

You have to add it to the hosts file as by default the hosts file is blank other than localhost.

Depends how you plan to use it - where do pretty names show up outside of hostnamectl? If you just want to set a machine-wide description, then setx pretty_name "My cool PC" -m can set a system env value that can be read anywhere. A hosts file entry can make a long name dns-resolvable, like allowing ping MyCoolPC-long-description to work, but it follows the same rules as host names (no spaces). It's exactly the same as linux /etc/hosts

@Cpt.Whale, is $Env:PRETTY_NAME a created-on-installation environment variable, or one that you arbitrarily decided upon for this? I ask because although indeed the fundamental functionality that pretty provides could be implemented in a custom manner in innumerable ways, the fact that it's standardised is what renders it attractive functionality - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/357925/3 explains quite well.

Yes, it's an arbitrary system environment variable name. The windows functionality you're looking for is offloaded to ldap object attributes in my opinion. And to nitpick - are pretty names really standardized in linux when they're null by default?

@Cpt.Whale, that's a good point, but I see enough uses online, and use it enough myself, that it at least appears so to me. However, now that you mention it, it's a little strange that the --pretty name isn't set to the --static ID by default, if it's null. I'll try to ascertain whether it's worth suggesting to SystemD. Do you know of a good resource that could explain what LDAP resource you reference? I'm unfamiliar with LDAP.

In an environment with an AD/Samba domain, each member device has an object like a user account with attributes like display name, description, os, etc. that can be queried with ldap. It's more for central management than pc customization, but I feel like if you have enough PCs to want pretty names, then you may already have somewhere to add that info into. Depends on your use case though - ldap is great for management, but a poor choice if you want to display that info on the login screen or something
